# Python Add Two Different Numpy Arrays To Nested Dictionaries

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, numpy, object-detection

Okay so I'm working on an object detection model. I can detect planes succesfully. But I want to send informations about these detections to users.

I have an empty dictionary:

```
planes= dict()
```

And I have a 2D array:

```
array1 = ([[  20.2765,   20.2508,  545.9968,   51.9848],
        [  56.2883, 1240.3577,  385.5900, 1268.1694],
        [ 502.5009, 1194.2896,  799.5756, 1221.9590],
        [  54.8439,  669.2018,  305.1923,  735.8934],
        [ 502.3042,  424.8962,  735.9933,  712.6230]])
```

And the other array:

```
array2 = [1, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

First array is the coordinates of planes, and the second array is the type of planes.

I want to form a JSON (or Python dict) on which these coordinates and types are connected to each other for each detected plane.

```
planes= {
  "plane1" : {
    "plane_coordinates" : [20.2765, 20.2508, 545.9968, 51.9848],
    "plane_type" : 1
  },
  "plane2" : {
    "plane_coordinates" : [56.2883, 1240.3577,  385.5900, 1268.1694],
    "plane_type" : 3
  },
  "plane3" : {
    "plane_coordinates" : [502.5009, 1194.2896,  799.5756, 1221.9590],
    "plane_type" : 3
  },
  "plane4" : {
    "plane_coordinates" : [54.8439,  669.2018,  305.1923,  735.8934],
    "plane_type" : 3
  },
  "plane" : {
    "plane_coordinates" : [502.3042,  424.8962,  735.9933,  712.6230],
    "plane_type" : 3
  }
}
```

I've been struggling with this for an hour but my newbie mind couldn't come up with a working solution.

I'd be thankful if anyone could help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the above stated problem:

```
 import numpy as np
 planes = dict()
 names = ['Plane1','Plane2','Plane3','Plane4']
 planes = dict()
 names = ['Plane1','Plane2','Plane3','Plane4']
 array1 = np.array([[  20.2765,   20.2508,  545.9968,   51.9848],
    [  56.2883, 1240.3577,  385.5900, 1268.1694],
    [ 502.5009, 1194.2896,  799.5756, 1221.9590],
    [  54.8439,  669.2018,  305.1923,  735.8934],
    [ 502.3042,  424.8962,  735.9933,  712.6230]])
  array2 = np.array([1, 3, 3, 3, 3])
  for ns in range(len(names)):
      planes[names[ns]] = {'Plane Coordinates': list(array1[ns]), 
     'Plane Type': array2[ns]}
```

This generates the desired results:

```
Planes = {'Plane1': {'Plane Coordinates': [20.2765, 20.2508, 545.9968, 51.9848],
                     'Plane Type': 1},
                     'Plane2': {'Plane Coordinates': [56.2883, 1240.3577, 385.59, 
                                                     1268.1694],
                                'Plane Type': 3},
                     'Plane3': {'Plane Coordinates': [502.5009, 1194.2896, 
                                                         799.5756, 1221.959],
                                 'Plane Type': 3},
                      'Plane4': {'Plane Coordinates': [54.8439, 669.2018, 
                                                        305.1923, 735.8934],
                                 'Plane Type': 3}}
```

Comment: If the above solution answers your question can you mark the query as closed?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, "closing a question" means a question is put on hold and cannot be answered until it is edited into a state where it confirms to SO rules and provides enough information to be answered. Maybe you wanted to ask to accept an answer, but that also wouldn't mean it is closed (and should be avoided because accepting an answer is not mandatory and completely up to the user).